# How do you Sum a Calculated Column?

Tags: list-view, calculated-column

I have a calculated column in a list and I would like to get a sum of that column in the view.  I can't use datasheet view, and I don't like the idea of a workflow because the user only sees a few records that are being summed.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you using to view your data? Data View Web Part? How are you filtering the records being shown to the user?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a SharePoint data view you can display the count of a column using XSL

```
< xsl:value-of select="sum(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@ColumnName)" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I hate bubbling old topics up, but I ran across this thread today and noticed it had lots of views and no answers.

A really simple way to do this is to create a workflow that runs automatically on new/edit list items and all it does is copy the calculated value to a "normal" number column and then sum that column in the view.

Comment: That would be my preferred approach - I know the OP said they wanted to avoid workflows - but that may not be a wise decision when this is something that just works out of the box. Only thing I'd add is that if you use a workflow, the calculated column may not be needed in the first place

Answer (score 0):

I don t there is a direct way to do this.
Please check the link below.I hope this would help.
http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/bambooteamblog/archive/2009/04/24/how-to-total-calculated-columns-in-a-sharepoint-list.aspx

Comment: this one refers to SharePoint Designer 2007, and the menu structure is quite different in 2010...

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this post and get some idea?

http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2010/03/30/sharepoint---summing-calculated-columns-by-groups-dvwp.aspx

Comment: This one is also an SP2007 post.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a DateView Web Part this blog post could help you out:

http://chanakyajayabalan.wordpress.com/2010/07/01/summing-calculated-columns-in-group-by-in-sharepoint-list-dataview-webpart/