# SP2010 sum a column using javascript?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

SP2010.

In Standard View, how do go about summing a column using javascript?

I've looked at this thread and none of the ideas fit.
[How do you Sum a Calculated Column?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24360/how-do-you-sum-a-calculated-column-in-sharepoint-2010)

Trying to work off this post but it doesn't apply to SP2010.
https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/jquery-for-everyone-total-calculated-columns.aspx